# Vectorizing Haversine distance calculation in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to calculate a distance matrix for a long list of locations identified by Latitude & Longitude using the [Haversine](https://github.com/mapado/haversine) formula that takes two tuples of coordinate pairs to produce the distance:

```
def haversine(point1, point2, miles=False):
    """ Calculate the great-circle distance bewteen two points on the Earth surface.

    :input: two 2-tuples, containing the latitude and longitude of each point
    in decimal degrees.

    Example: haversine((45.7597, 4.8422), (48.8567, 2.3508))

    :output: Returns the distance bewteen the two points.
    The default unit is kilometers. Miles can be returned
    if the ``miles`` parameter is set to True.

    """
```

I can calculate the distance between all points using a nested for loop as follows:

```
data.head()

   id                      coordinates
0   1   (16.3457688674, 6.30354512503)
1   2    (12.494749307, 28.6263955635)
2   3    (27.794615136, 60.0324947881)
3   4   (44.4269923769, 110.114216113)
4   5  (-69.8540884125, 87.9468778773)
```

using a simple function:

```
distance = {}
def haver_loop(df):
    for i, point1 in df.iterrows():
        distance[i] = []
        for j, point2 in df.iterrows():
            distance[i].append(haversine(point1.coordinates, point2.coordinates))

    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(distance, orient='index')
```

But this takes quite a while given the time complexity, running at around 20s for 500 points and I have a much longer list. This has me looking at vectorization, and I've come across `numpy.vectorize` ([(docs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), but can't figure out how to apply it in this context.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656475/python-speeding-up-geographic-comparison

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would provide your function as an argument to `np.vectorize()`, and could then use it as an argument to `pandas.groupby.apply` as illustrated below:

```
haver_vec = np.vectorize(haversine, otypes=[np.int16])
distance = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(haver_vec(df.coordinates, x.coordinates)))
```

For instance, with sample data as follows:

```
length = 500
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(length), 'coordinates':tuple(zip(np.random.uniform(-90, 90, length), np.random.uniform(-180, 180, length)))})
```

compare for 500 points:

```
def haver_vect(data):
    distance = data.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(haver_vec(data.coordinates, x.coordinates)))
    return distance

%timeit haver_loop(df): 1 loops, best of 3: 35.5 s per loop

%timeit haver_vect(df): 1 loops, best of 3: 593 ms per loop
```

Comment: `vectorize` is really just for convienience as far as I know it doesnt typically provide any speedup (at least any meaningful speedup)

Comment: Thanks, I needed to see an implementation sample, still new to all this and couldn't figure it out from the docs...

Answer (score 20):

From [`haversine's function definition`](https://github.com/mapado/haversine/blob/master/haversine/__init__.py), it looked pretty *parallelizable*. So, using one of the best tools for vectorization with NumPy aka [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and replacing the math funcs with the NumPy equivalents [`ufuncs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/ufuncs.html), here's one vectorized solution -

```
# Get data as a Nx2 shaped NumPy array
data = np.array(df['coordinates'].tolist())

# Convert to radians
data = np.deg2rad(data)                     

# Extract col-1 and 2 as latitudes and longitudes
lat = data[:,0]                     
lng = data[:,1]         

# Elementwise differentiations for lattitudes & longitudes
diff_lat = lat[:,None] - lat
diff_lng = lng[:,None] - lng

# Finally Calculate haversine
d = np.sin(diff_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat[:,None])*np.cos(lat) * np.sin(diff_lng/2)**2
return 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))
```

Runtime tests -

The other [`np.vectorize based solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502268/3293881) has shown some positive promise on performance improvement over the original code, so this section would compare the posted broadcasting based approach against that one.

Function definitions -

```
def vectotized_based(df):
    haver_vec = np.vectorize(haversine, otypes=[np.int16])
    return df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(haver_vec(df.coordinates, x.coordinates)))

def broadcasting_based(df):
    data = np.array(df['coordinates'].tolist())
    data = np.deg2rad(data)                     
    lat = data[:,0]                     
    lng = data[:,1]         
    diff_lat = lat[:,None] - lat
    diff_lng = lng[:,None] - lng
    d = np.sin(diff_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat[:,None])*np.cos(lat) * np.sin(diff_lng/2)**2
    return 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))
```

Timings -

```
In [123]: # Input
     ...: length = 500
     ...: d1 = np.random.uniform(-90, 90, length)
     ...: d2 = np.random.uniform(-180, 180, length)
     ...: coords = tuple(zip(d1, d2))
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(length), 'coordinates':coords})
     ...: 

In [124]: %timeit vectotized_based(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.12 s per loop

In [125]: %timeit broadcasting_based(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 68.7 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

start by getting all combinations using `itertools.product`

```
 results= [(p1,p2,haversine(p1,p2))for p1,p2 in itertools.product(points,repeat=2)]
```

that said Im not sure how fast it will be this looks like it might be a duplicate of [Python: speeding up geographic comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656475/python-speeding-up-geographic-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [haversine python library](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/), which provides a handy `haversine_vector` function for calculating distances from vectorized input. This functionality is particularly useful for fast distance calculations between **list of geographic coordinates**.

Here's a practical example from the library's documentation:

```py
from haversine import haversine_vector, Unit

lyon = (45.7597, 4.8422)  # Coordinates for Lyon (lat, lon)
paris = (48.8567, 2.3508)  # Coordinates for Paris
new_york = (40.7033962, -74.2351462)  # Coordinates for New York

distances = haversine_vector([lyon, lyon], [paris, new_york], Unit.KILOMETERS)

# Resulting array of distances:
# [392.21725956, 6163.43638211]
```

If you're working with a pandas dataframe that contains coordinate information and need to compute distances for multiple data points, you can easily achieve this by converting the coordinates to lists and using `haversine_vector`, as shown in the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from haversine import haversine_vector, Unit

# Assuming you have a pandas dataframe named 'df' with columns 'coord' and 'compared_coord'
df['distance'] = haversine_vector(df['coord'].to_list(), df['compared_coord'].to_list(), unit=Unit.METERS)
```

This code snippet efficiently calculates distances between corresponding pairs of coordinates in your dataframe, storing the results in a new 'distance' column.

For more details and installation instructions, you can visit the [haversine library's page on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/).