# Pairwise haversine distance calculation

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, haversine

I have two arrays with lat and long. I want to calculate distance between every pair of lat and long with every other pair of lat and long in the array. 
Here are my two arrays.

```
lat_array

array([ 0.33356456,  0.33355585,  0.33355585,  0.33401788,  0.33370132,
        0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33371075,  0.33371075,  0.33370132,
        0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33356488,  0.33356488,  0.33370132,
        0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33401788,  0.33362632,  0.33362632,
        0.33364007,  0.33370132,  0.33401788,  0.33401788,  0.33358399,
        0.33358399,  0.33358399,  0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33362632,
        0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33370132,
        0.33356488,  0.33356456,  0.33391071,  0.33370132,  0.33356488,
        0.33356488,  0.33356456,  0.33356456,  0.33356456,  0.33362632,
        0.33364804,  0.3336314 ,  0.33370132,  0.33370132,  0.33370132,
        0.33364034,  0.33359921,  0.33370132,  0.33360397,  0.33348863,
        0.33370132])
long_array

array([ 1.27253229,  1.27249141,  1.27249141,  1.27259085,  1.2724337 ,
        1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.27246931,  1.27246931,  1.2724337 ,
        1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.27254305,  1.27254305,  1.2724337 ,
        1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.27259085,  1.27250461,  1.27250461,
        1.27251211,  1.2724337 ,  1.27259085,  1.27259085,  1.27252134,
        1.27252134,  1.27252134,  1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.27250461,
        1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,
        1.27254305,  1.27253229,  1.27266808,  1.2724337 ,  1.27254305,
        1.27254305,  1.27253229,  1.27253229,  1.27253229,  1.27250461,
        1.27250534,  1.27250184,  1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,  1.2724337 ,
        1.27251339,  1.27223739,  1.2724337 ,  1.2722575 ,  1.27237575,
        1.2724337 ])
```

After conversion into radians. Now I want distance between first pair of lat and long with remaining pairs of lat and long and so on. And want to print the pairs and the corresponding distance.

This is what I am doing in python.

```
distance = []
R = 6371.0

for i in range(len(lat_array)):
   for j in (i+1,len(lat_array)):
      dlon = long_array[j]-long_array[i]
      dlat = lat_array[j]-lat_array[i]
      a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat_array[i]) * cos(lat_array[j]) *     
          sin(dlon / 2)**2
      c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

      distance.append(R * c)
```

It gives me an error `IndexError: index 56 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 56` 
Where I am doing it wrong? And how to make calculation faster if the array is big? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the code. Change

```
for j in (i+1,len(lat_array)):
```

to

```
for j in range(i+1,len(lat_array)):
```

Otherwise you're iterating a tuple consisting of two elements `i+1` and `len(lat_array)`. The second causes the error.

Comment: ohhh i see.. That was such a stupid mistake. But how do i print the pairs with a distance?

Answer (score 11):

Since this is currently Google's top result for "pairwise haversine distance" I'll add my two cents: This problem can be solved very quickly if you have access to `scikit-learn`. When looking at [`sklearn.metrics.`**`pairwise_distances`**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances) you'll note that the 'haversine' metric is not supported, however it is implemented in [`sklearn.neighbors.`**`DistanceMetric`**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric).

This means you can do the following:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

def sklearn_haversine(lat, lon):
    haversine = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
    latlon = np.hstack((lat[:, np.newaxis], lon[:, np.newaxis]))
    dists = haversine.pairwise(latlon)
    return 6371 * dists
```

Note that the concatenation of `lat` and `lon` is only necessary since they are seperate arrays. If you would pass them as a combined array of shape `(n_samples, 2)` you could call `haversine.pairwise` directly on them. Furthermore multiplication by `6371` is also only necessary if you need the distances in kilometers. E.g. this step wouldn't be necessary if you wanted to simply find the closest pair of points.

Verification:

```
In [87]: lat = np.array([ 0.33356456,  0.33355585,  0.33355585,  0.33401788,  0.33370132])

In [88]: lng = np.array([ 1.27253229,  1.27249141,  1.27249141,  1.27259085,  1.2724337 ])

In [89]: sklearn_haversine(lat, lng)
Out[89]:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.25227021,  0.25227021,  2.90953323,  1.05422047],
       [ 0.25227021,  0.        ,  0.        ,  3.00383463,  0.98975923],
       [ 0.25227021,  0.        ,  0.        ,  3.00383463,  0.98975923],
       [ 2.90953323,  3.00383463,  3.00383463,  0.        ,  2.2276139 ],
       [ 1.05422047,  0.98975923,  0.98975923,  2.2276139 ,  0.        ]])
```

Performance:

```
In [91]: lat = np.random.randn(1000)

In [92]: lng = np.random.randn(1000)

In [93]: %timeit original_app(lat,lng)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.46 s per loop

In [94]: %timeit vectorized_app1(lat,lng)
10 loops, best of 3: 86.7 ms per loop

In [95]: %timeit vectorized_app2(lat,lng)
10 loops, best of 3: 75.7 ms per loop

In [96]: %timeit sklearn_haversine(lat,lng)
10 loops, best of 3: 76 ms per loop
```

In conclusion you can get the output of Divakar's `vectorized_app1` with the speed of `vectorized_app2` in shorter and simpler code.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `lat` and `lng` as the lattitudes & longitudes arrays and that those have data in radians, here's one vectorized solution based upon  [`this other solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34517218/3293881) -

```
# Elementwise differentiations for lattitudes & longitudes
dflat = lat[:,None] - lat
dflng = lng[:,None] - lng

# Finally Calculate haversine using its distance formula
d = np.sin(dflat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat[:,None])*np.cos(lat) * np.sin(dflng/2)**2
hav_dists = 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))
```

Now, the above approach would give us output for all pairs irrespective of their order. Thus, we would have two distance outputs for the two pairs :`(point1,point2)` & `(point2,point1)`, even though the distances would be the same. So, to save on memory and hopefully better performance, you can create unique paired IDs with [`np.triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) and modify the earlier listed approach, like so -

```
# Elementwise differentiations for lattitudes & longitudes, 
# but not repeat for the same paired elements
N = lat.size
idx1,idx2 = np.triu_indices(N,1)
dflat = lat[idx2] - lat[idx1]
dflng = lng[idx2] - lng[idx1]

# Finally Calculate haversine using its distance formula
d = np.sin(dflat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat[idx2])*np.cos(lat[idx1]) * np.sin(dflng/2)**2
hav_dists = 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))
```

---

Function definitions -

```
def original_app(lat,lng):
    distance = []
    R = 6371.0
    for i in range(len(lat)):
       for j in range(i+1,len(lat)):
          dlon = lng[j]-lng[i]
          dlat = lat[j]-lat[i]
          a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat[i]) * cos(lat[j]) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
          c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
          distance.append(R * c)
    return distance

def vectorized_app1(lat,lng):                               
    dflat = lat[:,None] - lat
    dflng = lng[:,None] - lng
    d = np.sin(dflat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat[:,None])*np.cos(lat) * np.sin(dflng/2)**2
    return 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))

def vectorized_app2(lat,lng):                               
    N = lat.size
    idx1,idx2 = np.triu_indices(N,1)
    dflat = lat[idx2] - lat[idx1]
    dflng = lng[idx2] - lng[idx1]
    d =np.sin(dflat/2)**2+np.cos(lat[idx2])*np.cos(lat[idx1])*np.sin(dflng/2)**2
    return  2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))
```

Verify output -

```
In [78]: lat
Out[78]: array([ 0.33356456,  0.33355585,  0.33355585,  0.33401788,  0.33370132])

In [79]: lng
Out[79]: array([ 1.27253229,  1.27249141,  1.27249141,  1.27259085,  1.2724337 ])

In [80]: original_app(lat,lng)
Out[80]: 
[0.2522702110418014,
 0.2522702110418014,
 2.909533226553249,
 1.0542204712876762,
 0.0,
 3.003834632906676,
 0.9897592295963831,
 3.003834632906676,
 0.9897592295963831,
 2.2276138997714474]

In [81]: vectorized_app1(lat,lng)
Out[81]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.25227021,  0.25227021,  2.90953323,  1.05422047],
       [ 0.25227021,  0.        ,  0.        ,  3.00383463,  0.98975923],
       [ 0.25227021,  0.        ,  0.        ,  3.00383463,  0.98975923],
       [ 2.90953323,  3.00383463,  3.00383463,  0.        ,  2.2276139 ],
       [ 1.05422047,  0.98975923,  0.98975923,  2.2276139 ,  0.        ]])

In [82]: vectorized_app2(lat,lng)
Out[82]: 
array([ 0.25227021,  0.25227021,  2.90953323,  1.05422047,  0.        ,
        3.00383463,  0.98975923,  3.00383463,  0.98975923,  2.2276139 ])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [83]: lat = np.random.randn(1000)

In [84]: lng = np.random.randn(1000)

In [85]: %timeit original_app(lat,lng)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.11 s per loop

In [86]: %timeit vectorized_app1(lat,lng)
1 loops, best of 3: 263 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit vectorized_app2(lat,lng)
1 loops, best of 3: 224 ms per loop
```

Thus, for performance it seems `vectorized_app2` might be the way to go!

Comment: What does `lat[:,None]` mean?

Comment: @kfx That means we are extending lat from a 1D array to a 2D array by adding a singleton dimension (dimension with number of elements along that dimension as 1), so that when subtracted by `lat`, broadcasting would take place and we would have subtractions for  every element in `lat` against all other elements in it as a 2D array. Refer to the doc on broadcasting for more info - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 0):

The haversine_distances function introduced in scikit-learn 0.21.0 (released in 2019-05) can be used for this. Sample commands:

```
 % ipython     
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: 
import numpy as np
lat = np.array([ 0.33356456,  0.33355585,  0.33355585,  0.33401788,  0.33370132])
lon = np.array([ 1.27253229,  1.27249141,  1.27249141,  1.27259085,  1.2724337 ])
position = np.column_stack((lat, lon))
position
Out[1]: 
array([[0.33356456, 1.27253229],
       [0.33355585, 1.27249141],
       [0.33355585, 1.27249141],
       [0.33401788, 1.27259085],
       [0.33370132, 1.2724337 ]])

In [2]: 
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances
R = 6371.0
D1 = R * haversine_distances(position)
D1
Out[2]: 
array([[0.        , 0.25227021, 0.25227021, 2.90953323, 1.05422047],
       [0.25227021, 0.        , 0.        , 3.00383463, 0.98975923],
       [0.25227021, 0.        , 0.        , 3.00383463, 0.98975923],
       [2.90953323, 3.00383463, 3.00383463, 0.        , 2.2276139 ],
       [1.05422047, 0.98975923, 0.98975923, 2.2276139 , 0.        ]])
```

Ref:-

- https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v0.21.html#id16 - changelog
  entry
- https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v0.21.html#version-0-21-0 -
  shows the release date