# harvesine vectorization for vector list

Tags: python, performance, vectorization

I have a code snippet that computes a distance matrix between two lists of coordinates using the haversine function. While the current implementation works, it involves nested loops and can be time-consuming for large datasets. I am looking for a more efficient alternative that avoids the use of a for loop.

```
import numpy as np
from haversine import haversine
    
string_list_1 = [(20.00,-100.1),...]  # List of vector pair coordinates (lat,long)

string_list_2 = [(21.00,-101.1),...]  # Another list of pair coordinates

dist_mat = np.zeros((len(string_list_1), len(string_list_2)))

for i, coord1 in enumerate(string_list_1):
   dist_mat[i, :] = np.array([haversine(coord1, coord2) for coord2 in string_list_2])
```

I would appreciate suggestions or code examples for a more efficient and faster implementation that avoids the use of a for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vectorizing Haversine distance calculation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502254/vectorizing-haversine-distance-calculation-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`haversine`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html) from sklearn.metrics:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances
haversine_distances(string_list_1,string_list_2)
```

Comment: which is the metric of the output? km, meters

Comment: @PeCaDe click on the link and see more examples on how you first convert the degrees to radians then use the function, afterwhich you could multply by earth's radius to get the kilometers