# Geospatial analysis with AWS Redshift

Tags: geospatial, amazon-redshift

We are using Redshift for data warehousing. We have a lot of geospatial information in our data and we wanted to churn it to understand User behaviour.

Has anyone done any geospatial analysis with Redshift. Do not see any direct support for GIS tools with Redshift.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

As of today Redshift supports spatial queries. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/geospatial-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add some basic geospatial support to Reshshift using Python UDFs as described in this [blog](http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/01/19/how-to-work-with-spatial-data-in-amazon-redshift/).

Here is a [permanent link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656475/python-speeding-up-geographic-comparison/6659808#6659808) to the original solution used in the blog.

Comment: I would suggest you to read [why-is-linking-bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad)

Comment: A link to explain why linking is bad. :)